# Нужна помощь по выводу маркеров на google.maps

Tags: javascript, google-maps

Надо доделать часть, где берётся некое значение и проверяется на сервере нет ли пользователей с такими же id, и выводить их на google.maps как маркеры.

```
checkId: function (userId) {
        const checkBox = document.getElementById("myCheck");
        let value;
        if (checkBox.checked == true){
            value = 1;
        } else {
            value = 0;
        }
```

Я не понял эту часть кода, поскольку брал в сети, а где – сейчас не помню:

```
this.$http.post('/idAction',{ userId: userId, value: value})
                .then(response => {
                    this.supportMessages = response.body;
                })
```

Answer (score 0):

Этот кусок отправляет данные на обработчик и забирает результат обработки. 
Это всё, что отсюда видно.

UPD.

В контексте приложенного кода могу сказать следующее.

В данном случае Вы обращаетесь к обработчику по адресу `/idAction`, передавая туда строку json с неким id и неким value.

От обработчика в теории должен приходить ответ, если судить по коду, и заноситься в поле объекта, в контексте которого происходятся действия, с именем `supportMessages`.

Comment: как прописать функцию